postgres not working using docker gives error password authentication failed for user "pari"
hey i am trying to create a local postgres db using docker but i am not able to connect to it
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my -e POSTGRES_USER=pari -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
8678bafdea9d0566f6318f71165324c9316e9e7c89d4d186d355575c4bebed60
this is the command to start a db
postgresql://pari:my@localhost:5432/pari
this is the url i am tring to connect
E:\cohort\pg> node index.js
Failed to connect to the database: error: password authentication failed for user "pari"
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (E:\cohort\pg\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:283:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (E:\cohort\pg\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:122:29)
this is the error
not working.............................................................................................................................................................................
